# Error opening file in H5PY (File signature not found)

Tags: python, matlab, h5py

I've been using the following bit of code to open some HDF5 files, produced in MATLAB, in python using H5PY:

```
import h5py as h5
data='dataset.mat'
f=h5.File(data, 'r')
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (File signature not found)
```

I've checked that the files that I'm trying to open are version 7.3 MAT-files and are HDF5 format.  In fact I've used H5PY to open the same files successfully before.  I've confirmed that the files exist and are accessible so I'm not really sure where the error is coming from.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance : )

Comment: I guess you try to open hdf v. 4 file. HDF5 files have extension of `hdf5` or `h5`.

Answer (score 25):

Usually the message `File signature not found` indicates either:

**1. Your file is corrupted.**

... is what I think is most likely. You said you've opened the files before. Maybe you forgot closing your file-handle which can corrupt the file. 
Try checking the file with the HDF5 utility `h5debug` (available on command line if you've installed the hdf5 lib on your OS, check with `dpkg -s libhdf5-dev` on Linux).

**2. The file is not in HDF5 format.**

This is a known cause for your error message. But since you said you made sure, that this is the case and you've opened the files before, I'm giving this just for reference for others that may stumble here:

Since December 2015  (as of version 7.3), Matlab files use the HDF5 based format in their [MAT-File Level 5 Containers](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000440.shtml) (more [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf)). Earlier version MAT-files (v4 (Level 1.0), v6 and v7 to 7.2) are supported by and can be read with the `scipy` library:

```
import scipy.io
f = scipy.io.loadmat('dataset.mat')
```

---

Otherwise you may try other methods and see whether the error persists:

**PyTables** is an alternative to h5py and be found [here](http://www.pytables.org/).

```
import tables
file = tables.open_file('test.mat')
```

Install using

```
pip install tables
```

**Python MATLAB Engine** is an alternative to read MAT files, if you have matlab installed. Documentation is found here: [MATLAB Engine API for Python](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html).

```
import matlab.engine
mat = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
f = mat.load("dataset.mat", nargout=1)
```

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue with my .h5 file. And the problem was that I was not downloading the .h5 file correctly.

I was doing filename.h5->right_click->save link as, which was not downloading the file correctly(or may be the file was getting corrupted). Instead of doing that I downloaded the file as : selected the checkbox with filename.h5 and clicked on download and after that my code worked.

May be this help the one's who are doing the same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this happens when files are corrupted. I faced this problem and downloaded the file again and it resolves the issues.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is having this problem in Jupyter you should simply click on the checkbox of the file and click on the download button. 
this solution which I get from [here](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/757#issuecomment-412287475) helped me, hope it will help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Zipping the file with `tar -czvf zipfilename.tar.gz weightsfile` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This wont be the solution for everyone, but if you keep your data in the cloud on something like dropbox and forget about it, then when you try to open it you will get this error.

Data files get big and I often put folders of old work to be online only, then forget when I try to run the code again after a few months away...

So yeah, make sure anything you're accessing is set to 'make available offline' or whatever your cloud storage equivalent is and the error will go away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: literally just googled after having this issue again and came back to my own stack overflow answer without realising it... I never learn...

Answer (score 0):

Try other switches. The best one is `r+`:

```py
forecast_dataset = h5py.File(data_path, 'r+')
```

The file name may be a *byte string* or *unicode string*. Valid modes are:

- `r` :Readonly, file must exist (default)
- `r+`: Read/write, file must exist
- `w`:Create file, truncate if exists
- `w-` or `x` : Create file, fail if exists
- `a`: Read/write if exists, create otherwise