# OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found) / End of HDF5 error back trace

Tags: python, pandas, h5py, hdf

I have a small (< 6Mb) `.hdf` file (obtained from the [LAADS DAAC](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/) service). I have tried `pandas` and `h5py` to open it, to no avail (code shown below). I also tested the file with:

```
$ h5dump -n data.hdf
h5dump error: unable to open file "data.hdf"
```

and

```
$ h5debug data.hdf  
cannot open file
```

This would all seem to point to a corrupt file, but the weird thing is that [HDF View](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/) (v2.11) has **absolutely no issues opening the same file**.

What is going on here?

---

**1.**

```
import h5py
data = h5py.File(filename, 'r')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 394, in __init__
    swmr=swmr)
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 170, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

**2.**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.io.pytables.read_hdf(filename)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 603, in open
    self._handle = tables.open_file(self._path, self._mode, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 320, in open_file
    return File(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._g_new(filename, mode, **params)
  File "tables/hdf5extension.pyx", line 492, in tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new
tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 511, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1604, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
  File "H5Fsuper.c", line 413, in H5F__super_read
    file signature not found

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file 'data.hdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 368, in read_hdf
    store = HDFStore(path_or_buf, mode=mode, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 488, in __init__
    self.open(mode=mode, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 636, in open
    raise IOError(str(e))
OSError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 511, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1604, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
  File "H5Fsuper.c", line 413, in H5F__super_read
    file signature not found

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file 'data.hdf'
```

**3.**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.HDFStore(filename, mode='r')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 603, in open
    self._handle = tables.open_file(self._path, self._mode, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 320, in open_file
    return File(filename, mode, title, root_uep, filters, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._g_new(filename, mode, **params)
  File "tables/hdf5extension.pyx", line 492, in tables.hdf5extension.File._g_new
tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 511, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1604, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
  File "H5Fsuper.c", line 413, in H5F__super_read
    file signature not found

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file 'data.hdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 488, in __init__
    self.open(mode=mode, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gabriel/miniconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 636, in open
    raise IOError(str(e))
OSError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "H5F.c", line 511, in H5Fopen
    unable to open file
  File "H5Fint.c", line 1604, in H5F_open
    unable to read superblock
  File "H5Fsuper.c", line 413, in H5F__super_read
    file signature not found

End of HDF5 error back trace

Unable to open/create file 'data.hdf'
```

Comment: Most likely a directory problem.

Comment: What would a directory problem be?

Comment: A web search on the error gives links like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089950/error-opening-file-in-h5py-file-signature-not-found/43607837.  All the answers point to some sort of corruption during download.  Or file that isn't really `hdf5` format.

Comment: I thought it could be corrupted, but it happens to *all* the files I download from that service. If the file is not `hdf5` why is HDF View opening it with no issues?

Comment: HDFView can open HDF4 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the error message with:

```
In [88]: h5py.File('echo.py','r')                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-4c05cde6b6ff> in <module>
----> 1 h5py.File('echo.py','r')

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0, track_order, **kwds)
    406                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size,
    407                                fapl, fcpl=make_fcpl(track_order=track_order),
--> 408                                swmr=swmr)
    409 
    410             if isinstance(libver, tuple):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    171         if swmr and swmr_support:
    172             flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
--> 173         fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
    174     elif mode == 'r+':
    175         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

With the downloaded link (a 5M file):

```
1614:~/mypy$ h5debug ../Downloads/data.hdf 
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.0-patch1) thread 139633948224384:
  #000: ../../../src/H5F.c line 579 in H5Fopen(): unable to open file
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: ../../../src/H5Fint.c line 1208 in H5F_open(): unable to read superblock
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Read failed
  #002: ../../../src/H5Fsuper.c line 273 in H5F__super_read(): file signature not found
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Not an HDF5 file
cannot open file
```

---

Looks like the file is HDF4, not 5.

```
h5fromh4 -v ../Downloads/data.hdf
```

makes a `data.h5` file with one dataset "data"

```
In [3]: f = h5py.File('../Downloads/data.h5','r')                                              
In [4]: f                                                                                      
Out[4]: <HDF5 file "data.h5" (mode r+)>
In [5]: list(f.keys())                                                                         
Out[5]: ['data']
In [9]: f['data']                                                                              
Out[9]: <HDF5 dataset "data": shape (680, 451), type "<f8">
```

In `hdfview` I see the file is `HDFEOS_V2.19`

With `pyhdf` (and relevant `HDF4` libraries) I can:

```
In [3]: from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC                                                           
In [5]: f = SD('../Downloads/data.hdf', SDC.READ)                                              
In [6]: f.datasets()                                                                           
Out[6]: 
{'Longitude': (('Cell_Along_Swath:mod04', 'Cell_Across_Swath:mod04'),
  (680, 451),
  5,
  0),
...
```

And other datasets like those listed by `HDFView`.

Comment: If it is not a valid `hdf5` file why is HDF View able to open it with no issues? (BTW: the file contains data and looks, from within HDF View, like a perfectly valid data file)

Comment: I'm not an expert with `HDFView`.  In fact I haven't even installed it (with the java engine etc).  Nor am I familiar with the file source.

Comment: The file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w_BGmoJo-T3j44J5ngxSE4lAo6zEN0bs) in case you might want to chek it out. I'm pretty confident it is not corrupt.

Comment: The basic tools that come with `HDF5` and `h5py` can't read this file.  I have no idea why `view` can handle it.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj for confirming that the file can not be opened with python but it's handled without issues by HDF View .

Comment: I'm getting somewhere by treating it as a `HDF4` file.

Comment: Apparently it is an [HDF4 file](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1488). I'll look into reading this file with Python

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  In the preferences, under General->MAT-Files, my default selected format was "MATLAB Version 7 or later (save -v7)".  Change this to the first one "MATLAB Version 7.3 or later (save -v7.3)".  Then resave the data.  This seems to be the hdf5 data file format and you no longer get the error you are seeing.