# Unable to load in Python hdf file saved using Igor pro

Tags: python, hdf, igor

The file is Imported with no problem in Wolfran Matematica

using `Import['filename']` I get:

```
{"Amplitude", "trace #", "time (sec)"}
```

using `Import['filename', {"Datasets", "time (sec)"}]`   I get the time data

When I try to uploaded using pandas or h5py it does'n work

In pandas I used: `r = pd.read_hdf('filename')`

In h5py I used: `r = h5py.File('filename', 'r')`

Both approaches give similar error messages, mainly:

```
Unable to open file (file signature not found)
# can't auto open/close if we are using an iterator so delegate to the iterator
```

Comment: What is the Python code that you actually tried?

Comment: I update the question to give more details of what I have been trying.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Pandas `read_hdf()` function isn't meant to read arbitrary HDF files, just those created by Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html

Comment: Also, you haven't shown the code you used with h5py, only the Pandas code.

Comment: I add the line to try upload the data using h5py, both approaches send similar error messages.

Comment: Are your HDF file and your Python file in the same folder?

Comment: Also, are you sure that your HDF file is an HDF*5* file, not an HDF4 or other kind of file called HDF? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43607837/1643973) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046574/1643973).

Comment: I found out that it's a HDF4 file. Using pyhdf I was able to upload the file. Should I erase the question?