# OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, h5py

I am currently doing an assignment on deep learning by downloading the assignment files from github.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
import scipy
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage
from lr_utils import load_dataset

%matplotlib inline
```

You are given a dataset ("data.h5") containing: - a training set of m_train images labeled as cat (y=1) or non-cat (y=0) - a test set of m_test images labeled as cat or non-cat - each image is of shape (num_px, num_px, 3) where 3 is for the 3 channels (RGB). Thus, each image is square (height = num_px) and (width = num_px).

```
# Loading the data (cat/non-cat)
train_set_x_orig, train_set_y, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y, classes = load_dataset()
```

I ran the setup.sh file too but the error doesn't seem to go away.[image]

lr_utils.py file:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
    
    
def load_dataset():
    train_dataset = h5py.File('datasets/train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
    train_set_x_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_x"][:]) # your train set features
    train_set_y_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_y"][:]) # your train set labels

    test_dataset = h5py.File('datasets/test_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
    test_set_x_orig = np.array(test_dataset["test_set_x"][:]) # your test set features
    test_set_y_orig = np.array(test_dataset["test_set_y"][:]) # your test set labels

    classes = np.array(test_dataset["list_classes"][:]) # the list of classes
    
    train_set_y_orig = train_set_y_orig.reshape((1, train_set_y_orig.shape[0]))
    test_set_y_orig = test_set_y_orig.reshape((1, test_set_y_orig.shape[0]))
    
    return train_set_x_orig, train_set_y_orig, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y_orig, classes
```

Kindly help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error opening file in H5PY (File signature not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089950/error-opening-file-in-h5py-file-signature-not-found)

Comment: I can give you this advice, ==> check your list of .h5 files, I, navely, had a long list and I had a .py File inthere, so I had always this message error "unable to open file (file signature not found)"

Comment: You might want to take a look at ["_Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/20170164)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by downloading uncorrupted .h5 files and putting them in the folder datasets/ in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

The files you downloaded are corrupted. You can visit https://github.com/abdur75648/Deep-Learning-Specialization-Coursera to download the uncorrupted files.

Answer (score 0):

you can download uncorrupted files from here :
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/muhammeddalkran/catvnoncat

and replace it in the directory of the corrupted files