# Load joblib file with custom metrics

Tags: python, keras, joblib

I am training multiple models (on Google Colab) and saving them using joblib. I am then downloading these files and loading them using joblib, but I am getting the following error;

Unable to restore custom object of type _tf_keras_metric

I am compiling the models using metrics=['accuracy', specificity, tf.keras.metrics.Precision()], where specificity is a custom metric function from https://www.sabinasz.net/unbalanced-classes-machine-learning/.

```
mobilenet_model = MobileNetV3Small(include_top=True, weights=None, classes=2, input_shape=(100, 100, 3))
mobilenet_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', specificity, tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])
trained_model  = mobilenet_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

joblib.dump(trained_model, 'mobilenet_model.joblib')
```

I tried to load them using keras.models.load_model but I get a Error opening file (File signature not found) which according to [Error opening file in H5PY (File signature not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089950/error-opening-file-in-h5py-file-signature-not-found) means the file is corrupt (I imagine that the way joblib saves models is not compatible with keras's save_model function).

I tried using keras.models.save_model to save a file and passing in custom_objects={'specificity': specificity, 'precision': tf.keras.metrics.Precision()}, but the model seems to be saved without the pretrained weights because when I evaluate it, it only has 0.5 accuracy, when it was getting 0.9 when I trained it.

So what can I do?

Comment: do you use exactly the same version of keras/tensorflow on both computers?

Comment: I just checked, and both Google Colab and my computer are using version 2.8.0 for both keras and tensorflow